# Rails wait for Turbolinks to be loaded to execute JavaScript import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, turbolinks

Ich want to call a JavaScript function within the **application.html.erb**. The function is imported and provided in the **application.js**:

```
import myFunction from 'myJSModule';
window.myFunction = myFunction;
```

I am using turbolinks and vite_rails and it seems like the JS function is called before the application.js is loaded and it is undefined.

**Example:**

application.html.erb

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     
   </script>
   <%= vite_javascript_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track': "reload" %>
   <%= render "layouts/partial" %>  # here I call the window.myFunction
 </head>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

layouts/_partial.html.erb

```
<script>
  window.myFunction
</script>
```

**Behaviour:** 
`window.myFunction` is undefined. 
When I try to call the function in the console, *after* the side is loaded, then it is defined.
Also when I wait for the turbolinks:load event:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() { window.myFunction }
```

The Problem with the event is, that it is triggered every navigation event, but I want to call the function only when the partial is re-rendered.
I recently migrated from webpack to vite. For webpack the solution seemed to be to move the render partial below the java_script_tag. Unfortunately, this does not work with with vite.

Answer (score 2):

I could find a solution. Appending the attribute type of the script with `module`:

```
<script type="module">
  window.myFunction
</script>
```